# Google Map with Bouncing Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to get a Google Map with bouncing marker using Google API3. My code is below.

The things that I cannot do so far are the following:

1. The marker is bouncing continuously; I need it to bounce once.
2. I need to disable the mouse wheel move for zooming.
3. I'd like to change the color of the map to light blue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Map with Marker</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
     ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });


marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would be really thankful if anybody can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Is better if you ask a question at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question you can set the related option scrollwheel to false in options eg:

```
var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.9000, 25.3167),
            zoom: 4,
           scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first question you can simply use a setAnimation function based ond timeout

```
marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
setTimeout(function(){ marker.setAnimation(null); }, 1000);
```

this way bounce for a second, you can adjust the duration you prefer